# How to correctly setup Varnish cache on Magento 2.3 with SSL?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, varnish, ssl

I am trying to configure Varnish cache on Magento 2.3 with SSL termination, but no luck so far.

Here is my configuration:

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerAdmin contact@website.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/
     ServerName website.com
     ServerAlias www.website.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias www.website.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/

        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/website.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/website.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/website.com.ca-bundle
        <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "52.56.108.15";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
```

/etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
     -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
     -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
     -p thread_pool_min=${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS} \
     -p thread_pool_max=${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS} \
     -p http_resp_hdr_len=65536 \
     -p http_resp_size=98304 \
 -p workspace_backend=98304 \
     -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
     -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
```

Magento Cache config:

```
Access list: 127.0.0.1
Backend host: 52.56.108.15
Backend port: 8080
Grace period: 300
```

Here is how my response headers look at this point:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 18:00:29 GMT
Expires: Thu, 22 Mar 2018 18:00:29 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fh1hcnrcvs4u25lp1kqq7sv8br; expires=Fri, 22-Mar-2019 19:00:29 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=website.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: form_key=Hu9gu1oJeyjVzCjm; expires=Fri, 22-Mar-2019 19:00:29 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=website.com
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Can anyone help with this issue? Thanks in advance!